# Numpy AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code:

```
def sigmoid(X, T): 
    return (1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-1.0*np.dot(X, T))))
```

And this line gives me error

> "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'". X, t are Numpy ndarray.

Comment: Looks like you re-assigned `np` to a float value.

Comment: Would `X` or `T` happen to have accidentally been created with a dtype of `object` instead of `float64`?

Comment: No, re-assigned was not happen. type(X) is numpy ndarray, type(X[0][0]) is float

Comment: Hm. But when i implement X = X.astype(float), everything works fine.

Comment: Try `print X.dtype, T.dtype` and see what you get. You most likely have the wrong dtype.

Answer (score 22):

Probably there's something wrong with the input values for X and/or T. The function from the question works ok:

```
import numpy as np
from math import e

def sigmoid(X, T):
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-1.0 * np.dot(X, T)))

X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5, 0, 0]])
T = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 4]])

print(X.dot(T))
# Just to see if values are ok
print([1. / (1. + e ** el) for el in [-5, -10, -15, -16]])
print()
print(sigmoid(X, T))
```

Result:

```
[[15 16]
 [ 5 10]]

[0.9933071490757153, 0.9999546021312976, 0.999999694097773, 0.9999998874648379]

[[ 0.99999969  0.99999989]
 [ 0.99330715  0.9999546 ]]
```

Probably it's the dtype of your input arrays. Changing X to:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/[...]/stackoverflow_sigmoid.py", line 24, in <module>
    print sigmoid(X, T)
  File "/[...]/stackoverflow_sigmoid.py", line 14, in sigmoid
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-1.0 * np.dot(X, T)))
AttributeError: exp
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I didn't know about dtype and used just type(X). I did X = X.astype(float) and it is worked.

Comment: so array operations like mean() could not be used in arrays with dype=object? I wonder why?

Comment: this error message is very misleading: the problem is that the `dtype` is in fact `numpy.object`, but the message says `numpy.float64` has no attribute `log10`, or whatever arithmetic method

Answer (score 9):

You convert type `np.dot(X, T)` to float32 like this:

`z=np.array(np.dot(X, T),dtype=np.float32)`

```
def sigmoid(X, T):
    return (1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z)))
```

Hopefully it will finally work!