# Python / Numpy AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, attributeerror

I'm going to post this here because it's quite a chestnut and caused me some head-scratching.  It's arguably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557337/numpy-attributeerror-float-object-has-no-attribute-exp) posted four years ago but I'll post it again in case someone has the specific pandas-numpy incompatibility that I have encountered here.  Or maybe someone will come up with a better answer.

Code snippet:

```
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

# TODO: This raises AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'
xr = xw + L*np.sin(θr)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MIP_MPC_demo.py", line 561, in <module>
    main()
  File "MIP_MPC_demo.py", line 557, in main
    animation = create_animation(model, data_recorder)
  File "MIP_MPC_demo.py", line 358, in create_animation
    xr = xw + L*np.sin(θr)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

What I've tried so far:

```
(Pdb) type(np)
<class 'module'>
(Pdb) np.sin
<ufunc 'sin'>
(Pdb) type(θr)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
(Pdb) np.sin(θr.values)
*** AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'
(Pdb) θr.dtype
dtype('O')
(Pdb) np.sin(θr)
*** AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'
(Pdb) θr.sin()
*** AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sin'
(Pdb) θr.values.sin()
*** AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sin'
(Pdb) θr.values.max()
nan
(Pdb) np.max(θr)
0.02343020407511865
(Pdb) np.sin(θr)
*** AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'
(Pdb) np.sin(θr[0])
0.0
```

On a side-note, the exception is misleading to say the least.  It's been four years since the other person posted the issue.  Does anyone else agree that this should be modified and any suggestions on how?  What is the explanation for the exception?  Is numpy doing some kind of map operation and trying to call the `sin` method of each element of `θr`?

I will post the answer shortly...

Comment: What is the type of `θr.values`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails for the same reason as:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=object)
np.sin(arr)
# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

When `np.sin` is called on an object array, it tries to call the `sin` method of each element.

If you know the dtype of `θr.values`, you can fix this with:

```
arr = np.array(θr.values).astype(np.float64)  # assuming the type is float64
np.sin(arr)  # ok!
```

Comment: You are correct.  However, in my case, I did not start with a numpy array.  If I had it would have had the right dtype.  I created an empty pandas DataFrame and then filled it with float values.  The default type for a DataFrame is object and it doesn't change if you fill it with floats....  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix if you know the possible data types of θr:

```
xr = xw + L*np.sin(θr.astype(float))
```

Better solution.  Get the data type right from the beginning when creating the dataframe.

Instead of:

```
self.data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n), columns=columns)
...

data.iloc[i, :] = new_data_dict
```

(Which I was using)

Use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n), columns=columns, dtype=float)
```

or:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.empty((n, len(columns)), columns=columns)
```

or:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.full((n, len(columns), np.nan), columns=columns)
```