# Origin of AttributeError: object has no attribute 'cos'

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror

I came upon this post : [Sympy to numpy causes the AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'cos'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753260/sympy-to-numpy-causes-the-attributeerror-symbol-object-has-no-attribute-cos), and would like to understand a bit more the origin of the exception.

To be more precise, Eric answered : "This type of error occurs when you call np.cos(a_symbol), which apparently translates under-the-hood in numpy to a_symbol.cos()."
I would like to understand how/where this behaviour origins from : how does np.cos(x) can be translated under the hood into x.cos() ?

I tried to reproduce the raise of the exception, but couldn't trace it's origin:

```
import numpy as np
class toto:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
foo = toto(4)

class tata:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def cos(self):
        print(self.x)

bar = tata(5)

try:
    np.cos(foo)
except:
    np.cos(bar)
```

This prints 5.

Cheers

Comment: This occurs when a math function (at least `ufunc`) is applied to an object dtype array. `numpy` iterates through the object elements and tries to apply a similarly named method. I've answered a few similar attribute error questions.

Comment: This AttributeError also occurs when applied to a simple object (see my post that I edited) - there are no notion of array or iteration, am I right ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662823/different-behavior-of-arithmetics-on-dtype-float-object-and-float is another exploration of this behavior.

Comment: `numpy` first makes an array from your object  `np.cos( np.array(bar))`.

Comment: Another answer from @Eric, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971708/python-numpy-attributeerror-float-object-has-no-attribute-sin

Comment: @hpaulj so does every ufunc tries to "cast" input into array ? I realized that if the object has a \__array__() method that return an array-version of the object, the np.cos works just fine. Yet that doesn't explain how defining a cos() method makes it work as well... It seems that the array method take precedence over the cos method.

Comment: `np.cos(x)` is handled in the same way as `np.cos([x,x,x])`.  The key variable is what's the nature of `np.array(x)` or `np.array([x,x,x])`.  Is the result a numeric dtype or object dtype?

Comment: Indeed : so basically, if my custom object has a \__array__ method, the result is sent to np.cos. If it has a numerical dtype, it all works fine, but if if has a "object" dtype, then we get the AttributeError for cos on the value that was cast into ndarray type (ex : np.cos(np.array(5, dtype=object)) raises an AttributeError 'int' object has no attribute 'cos').
BUT if my custom object has no \__array__ method, numpy tries to call the cos method of the custom object (ex : toto.cos()).

Comment: But that doesn't explain why... ("source-code wise")

Comment: I've never tried to locate the C code that handles object dtypes for `ufuncs`.