# Apply function along ranges in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following numpy array:

```
a = np.arange(20)
```

And also an array containing indices as follows:

```
ix = np.array([4,10,15])
```

I've been trying to come up with a vectorized solution to the following question: How can I apply a function along `a` being splitted using the indices in `ix`?

So say I where to split `a` with `np.split` (I'm only using `np.split` here to illustrate the groups to which I would like to apply a function here):

```
np.split(a,ix)

[array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14]),
 array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19])]
```

And say for instance I'd like to take the sum on each chunk, so giving:

```
[6, 39, 60, 85]
```

How could I vectorize this using `numpy`?

Comment: I don't think you can vectorize your ops on that kind of array. Can you use pandas?

Comment: Well yes I could but looking for a numpy solution for a better performance

Comment: You are looking for sum only or for a general solution?

Comment: General. Was just an example

Comment: A solution with sum is good enough though, the idea should be the same

Comment: In general I believe that all numpy solutions will pass for filling the holes in the array so, you can fill the holes with 0 for sum, but that will not help for mutiplicatio for instance.

Comment: My specific problem consists on finding the minimum and maximum of each chunk. So if sum works that should too

Comment: I have an inkling from an answer I saw and used from Divakar a while back; unfortunately that means I have little memory of how it works till I get back home to see the code in a couple of hours.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043366/4001592

Comment: It wasn't that one in the case im thinking of but that guy has some serious tricks up his sleeve so it's a decent bet he has solved something similar

Comment: Yes! That could indeed be a first step to get a proper ndarray. Thanks @DanielMesejo

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best solution, but you could convert the list of arrays with different sizes to list of array of fixed size by adding zeros. And then implement a function like sum that does not get affected by zeros.

See an example below.

```
a = np.arange(20)
ix = np.array([4,10,15])
b = np.split(a,ix)
print(b)
```

results in

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14]),
 array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19])]
```

Then use itertools to convert list to array [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values)

```
import itertools
c = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*b, fillvalue=0))).T
print(c)
```

which results in

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  0  0]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14  0]
 [15 16 17 18 19  0]]
```

then sum it using

```
np.sum(c, axis = 1)
```

results in

```
array([ 6, 39, 60, 85])
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution even though it's not numpy based, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Don't dismiss `zip_longest` just because it doesn't have a `np.` prefix!  It's one the nicer ways of padding lists to a uniform length.

Comment: Yes I think this solution is indeed nice! I'm only stressing on that fact because I did explicitly mention that I was looking for a numpy solution

Comment: But why do you want a numpy solution?

Comment: Because I would be applying the solution to n arrays as a and ix. So ideally I would like to stack them together and perform vectorized operations over them. I strart of with a 3dim array, perform some operations and end up with these 2dim arrays a and ix. Made it a 1dim array here for simplicity. But it should be the same if the solution is numpy based. If python loops are used it won't scale as well.

Answer (score 1):

`split` produces a list of arrays, which may differ in length.  It actually does so iteratively

```
In [12]: alist = []
In [13]: alist.append(a[0:idx[0]])
In [14]: alist.append(a[idx[0]:idx[1]])
In [15]: alist.append(a[idx[1]:idx[2]])
....
```

Applying `sum` to each element of the list individually makes sense:

```
In [11]: [np.sum(row) for row in alist]
Out[11]: [6, 39, 60, 85]
```

When you have a list of arrays that differ in shape, it's a good bet that you'll have to do a Python level iteration on it.

Fast 'vectorize' means performing the calculations in compiled code.  Most that is built around multidimensional arrays, e.g. 2d ones.  If your `split` had produced equal size array, you could use `np.sum` with the appropriate axis parameter.

```
In [23]: a1 = a.reshape(4,5)
In [24]: a1
Out[24]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
In [25]: np.sum(a1, axis=1)
Out[25]: array([10, 35, 60, 85])
```

Sometimes we can play tricks to cast the problem into a n-d one, for example if your first array of the split were padded with a 0.  But that casting itself might require iteration.

As raised here (and its links) [Origin of AttributeError: object has no attribute 'cos'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538582/origin-of-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute-cos)
math (`ufunc`) functions applied to object dtype arrays, ends up delegating the action to corresponding methods of the objects.  But that still involves a (near)Python level iteration over the objects.

---

Some timings:

```
In [57]: timeit [np.sum(row) for row in alist]
31.7 µs ± 1.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [58]: timeit np.sum(list(itertools.zip_longest(*alist, fillvalue=0)),axis=0)
25.2 µs ± 82 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [59]: timeit np.nansum(pd.DataFrame(alist), axis=1)
908 µs ± 28.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [61]: timeit np.frompyfunc(sum,1,1)(alist)
12.9 µs ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

In this last case the Python `sum` is faster than than `np.sum`.  But that's true with the list comprehension as well:

```
In [63]: timeit [sum(row) for row in alist]
6.86 µs ± 13.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And with Divakar's wiz-bang `fillna`, [Numpy: Fix array with rows of different lengths by filling the empty elements with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037893/numpy-fix-array-with-rows-of-different-lengths-by-filling-the-empty-elements-wi/32043366#32043366)

```
In [70]: timeit numpy_fillna(np.array(alist)).sum(axis=1)
44.2 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Once you have a multidimensional array, the numpy code is fast.  But if start with a list, even a list of arrays, Python list methods often are faster.  The time it takes to construct an array (or Dataframe) is never trivial.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that each array may differ in length. No. Split here was to make the example easy to understand. Just wondering if there was an alternative to python level iteration

Comment: The core of true vectorization is to perform the action in compiled code, using the standard numpy building blocks.  In most cases that requires rectangular multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A pandas solution will be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.arange(20)

ix = np.array([4, 10, 15])

data = pd.DataFrame(np.split(a, ix))

print(np.nansum(data, axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
[ 6. 39. 60. 85.]
```

Comment: This works because `DataFrame` pads the short rows with `NaN`.  But creating frame is a very slow process.  My list comprehension is 30x faster.